# What is the best way to add information to an already answered question?

Tags: discussion

Should i comment the answer or add another answer referring to the original poster? See this case for example: [Is the government a producer, a consumer, or both?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/is-the-government-a-producer-a-consumer-or-both/17832#17832)

Comment: What kind of information? Towards answering the question?

Comment: I just added an example in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, anyone can edit an answer by anybody else, to include additional material, but I haven't seen it happening on any site, probably out of respect for the original author of the answer. Usually, a comment below an answer suggests to the author some additional info/data/result that he could include in his answer, and then it is up to the author to do that or not.

Regarding whether to post a separate answer, mostly it boils down to the *length* of the additional contribution. In the example you provide, your answer is more of a comment below my answer, rather than a separate answer (and have in mind that comments, although officially looked-upon by the SE approach, are avidly read by users).

And by the way, since my answer mentions roads-infrastructure, why do you think it does not include the investing activities of the government?

Comment: Thanks! In my case, using roads again was a bad example - it could be a military base, hospital, school. I wanted to tell that there is yet a third role of the government, which is to be an investor itself, without being a producer or consumer.